# Xtext integration with Python

Tags: python, dsl, xtext

I am new to DSL area and I am developing a DSL language. I will need to provide an editor to write the in that language what makes Xtext a very good option. However, some of my libraries are in Python and I need to "run" the DSL in python. Any idea how to integrate them?

the perfect scenario would be:

Xtext -> Pass the Tokens to Python -> Semantics in Python

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think the answer is quite simple:

I can generate the code in a XML or pyconf format and read from python
:)

thank you anyway